# Couln't match type

Tags: haskell

I have a problem with this code:

```
 rango2 :: Int -> [Int] -> [[Int]] -> [Int]
 rango2 a b list = if (verif (map(+list!!a!!2)(list!!a)) (map(-list!!a!!2)(list!!a)) (b)) then [1]
              else [0]

 verif :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int] -> Bool
 verif a b c = if ((c!!0 < ((a!!0)+1)) && (((c!!0)+1) > b!!0) && (c!!1 < ((a!!1)+1)) && (((c!!1)+1) > b!!1)) then True
          else False
```

When run, it produces this error:

```
Couldn't match type `Int' with `Int -> Int'
Expected type: [[Int -> Int]]
  Actual type: [[Int]]
In the first argument of `(!!)', namely `list'
In the first argument of `(!!)', namely `list !! a'
In the expression: list !! a !! 2
```

Comment: [`map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:map) expects two arguments, the first of which is a function. You seem to be passing it three arguments in `rango2`.

Comment: The fact that you are using `x!!0` everywhere probably indicates you would be best served by a [basic haskell tutorial](http://learnyouahaskell.com/).

Comment: @user2407038: while `!!0` is certainly not idiomatic, it's not really worse than `head`, which (though generally frowned upon) is sometimes reasonable to use. What's really bad (though, again, sometimes ratifiable) is indexing lists at bigger indices: it's not just unsafe but also inefficient. And these "magic indices" `!!2` are bad for quite different reasons as well: readability, type deduction, refactoring robustness... Probably, a lot of the OP's lists should better be meaningful ADTs.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I didn't mean `!!0` vs `head`, I meant `!!0` vs pattern matching on `x:xs` and then handling the empty list more gracefully.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is `(-list!!a!!2)`. Yes, this looks like an operator section, analogously to `(+list!!a!!2)`. But, alas, the minus operator is traditionally used also as a lone negative-prefix, and Haskell has put that special case into the language; so `(-list!!a!!2)` is actually just a negative number and not a subtractor-function. You can use `(subtract $ list!!a!!2)`.